# Accessing values in a matrix for a column previous to the first column?

Tags: arrays, julia

I am trying to access elements of the previous columns than first column.

For example in **python** if i try to access elements before the first column `0` it will return an `empty array`.

```py
import numpy as np
x = np.matrix([[ 1,  2, 10],
 [ 1,  4, 2],
 [ 2,  3,  2],
 [ 2,  3,  6]])
a = x[:, 0]
print('\n a is \n', a)
b = x[:, :0]
print('\n b is \n',b)

Output: -->

 a is 
 [[1]
 [1]
 [2]
 [2]]

 b is 
 []
```

But julia does not behave in such manner.

My trial in julia:

```
array = [1 2 3;3 4 5;2 3 4;1 2 3]
a = array[:, 1]
b = array[:, 1-1]

Output :-->

BoundsError: attempt to access 4×3 Array{Int64,2} at index [1:4, 0]

Stacktrace:
 [1] throw_boundserror(::Array{Int64,2}, ::Tuple{Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}},Int64}) at .\abstractarray.jl:541
 [2] checkbounds at .\abstractarray.jl:506 [inlined]
 [3] _getindex at .\multidimensional.jl:742 [inlined]
 [4] getindex(::Array{Int64,2}, ::Function, ::Int64) at .\abstractarray.jl:1060
 [5] top-level scope at In[1166]:1
 [6] include_string(::Function, ::Module, ::String, ::String) at .\loading.jl:1091
```

However, to replicate such operation I tried to implement `try and catch` method and use it over the loop to see what happens when i try accessing different columns. The output is always an empty array.

```
for i in 1:3
    try
       b = array[:, :i-1] 
    catch 
        b = []
    end
    println("\b b in $i is $b")
end

Output :--->

 b in 1 is Any[]
 b in 2 is Any[]
 b in 3 is Any[]
```

May I know how can I access row elements from `first_column - 1` to `last_column - 1`, where `first_column - 1` returns an empty array but rest returns data from the matrix.

Comment: I have posted this question on discourse, please refer the following link: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/accessing-values-in-a-matrix-for-a-column-previous-to-the-first-column/59634

Answer (score 1):

The answer to my question is provided by @ettersi on julia discourse, I am posting it here for reference. Please follow the link mentioned in the comment to access the discourse page.

*ANSWER!*

```
julia> array = [1 2 3;3 4 5;2 3 4;1 2 3]
4×3 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  2  3
 3  4  5
 2  3  4
 1  2  3

julia> array[:, 1:0]
4×0 Matrix{Int64}
```